# What is URL for Kibana UI

Tags: kubernetes, kibana, efk

http://grs-preprodkubemaster01:5601/kibana

I have followed docs and installed Kibana, When I used the service as type: LoadBalancer, the service isn't 
coming up, so I deleted the type: LoadBalancer and let it default to ClusterIP, it came up fine. (Note I don't have AWS)
But, I am not sure how to access the UI, I tried this URL but its not working.
http://my-preprodkubemaster01/api/v1/proxy/namespaces/kube-system/services/elasticsearch-logging/app/kibana
any ideas how to access the Kibana UI. I checked service, deployment and everything is green check.

Another thing I tried is this URL with this URL which I got from the command kubectl cluster-info
https://10.123.24.107:6443/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/services/kibana-logging/proxy
However, this is showing me  this error

```
{
kind: "Status",
apiVersion: "v1",
metadata: { },
status: "Failure",
message: "services "kibana-logging" is forbidden: User "system:anonymous" cannot get services/proxy in the namespace "kube-system"",
reason: "Forbidden",
details: {
name: "kibana-logging",
kind: "services"
},
code: 403
}
```

So, as another try I used Kibana service as NodePort, but that didn't work either.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: kibana-logging
  namespace: kube-system
  labels:
    k8s-app: kibana-logging
    kubernetes.io/cluster-service: "true"
    addonmanager.kubernetes.io/mode: Reconcile
    kubernetes.io/name: "Kibana"
spec:
  selector:
    k8s-app: kibana-logging
  type: NodePort
  ports:
  - port: 5601
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: ui
    nodePort: 30887

$  kubectl -n kube-system get rc,svc,cm,po
NAME                        TYPE        CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)          AGE
svc/elasticsearch-logging   ClusterIP   10.98.10.182     <none>        9200/TCP         12m
svc/heapster                ClusterIP   10.107.184.85    <none>        80/TCP           3d
svc/kibana-logging          NodePort    10.102.254.129   <none>        5601:30887/TCP   12m
svc/kube-dns                ClusterIP   10.96.0.10       <none>        53/UDP,53/TCP    3d
svc/kubernetes-dashboard    ClusterIP   10.105.30.246    <none>        80/TCP           3d
svc/monitoring-influxdb     ClusterIP   10.109.144.39    <none>        8086/TCP         3d
```

I would like to know what URL I should be using to access the Kibana UI. Please note that I have npot tried to do kubectl proxy and I would like to have it work without it

Answer (score 1):

Use the NodePort you defined in your service:

```
https://10.123.24.107:30887
```

Comment: I tried http://abc-preprodkubemaster01:30887/api/v1/proxy/namespaces/kube-system/services/kibana-logging/app/kibana, but getting 
404
{
statusCode: 404,
error: "Not Found"
}

Comment: and without   /api/v1/proxy/namespaces/....  ? just the url I wrote above.

Answer (score 1):

The most common way to expose internal server outside the cluster is an [Ingress](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/).

First, you need to have an Ingress controller running in your Kubernetes cluster.
There are two types of maintained Ingress controllers - [GCE](https://git.k8s.io/ingress-gce/README.md) and [nginx](https://git.k8s.io/ingress-nginx/README.md)

Then, you need to create a [yaml](https://github.com/kubernetes/website/blob/master/content/en/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress.yaml) file as shown below and change it according to your needs:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: test-ingress
spec:
  backend:
    serviceName: testsvc
    servicePort: 80
```

When you create it using `kubectl create -f`, you should see something like this:

```
$ kubectl get ingress
NAME                RULE          BACKEND        ADDRESS
test-ingress        -             testsvc:80     1.2.3.4
```

In this example, `1.2.3.4` is the IP allocated by Ingress controller.

When you have all things in place, you'll be able to access your application (Kibana) by IP `1.2.3.4`

Please find more examples and use cases in [Ingress documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/)

You can also expose a Kubernetes service without using the Ingress resource:

1. [Service.Type=LoadBalancer](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#type-loadbalancer)
2. [Service.Type=NodePort](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#type-nodeport)
3. [Port Proxy](https://git.k8s.io/contrib/for-demos/proxy-to-service)

Comment: I have a ingress already, and dashboard is running there, as soon as I add config for another ingress like the one above dashboard goes down and kibana also doesn't come up

Comment: Could you provide yaml for dashboard ingress, and for kibana (pod, service, ingress)?

Answer (score 1):

I got it to work with these changes in ingress config

```
    apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
    kind: Ingress
    metadata:
     name: kube
  namespace: kube-system
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.org/rewrites: "serviceName=kubernetes-dashboard rewrite=/;serviceName=kibana-logging rewrite=/"
spec:
  rules:
  - host: HOSTNAME_OF_MASTER
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /kube-ui/
        backend:
          serviceName: kubernetes-dashboard
          servicePort: 80
      - path: /kibana/
        backend:
          serviceName: kibana-logging
          servicePort: 5601
```

and my Kibana serive is setup as Nodeport

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: kibana-logging
  namespace: kube-system
  labels:
    k8s-app: kibana-logging
    kubernetes.io/cluster-service: "true"
    addonmanager.kubernetes.io/mode: Reconcile
    kubernetes.io/name: "Kibana"
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
  - port: 5601
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: ui
  selector:
    k8s-app: kibana-logging
```

and dashboard is also configured as this

```
# ------------------- Dashboard Service ------------------- #
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  labels:
    k8s-app: kubernetes-dashboard
  name: kubernetes-dashboard
  namespace: kube-system
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
    - port: 80
      targetPort: 9090
  selector:
    k8s-app: kubernetes-dashboard
```

once you have the svc running you can access kibana using the NodePort from any node. Example: http://node01_ip: 31325/app/kibana

```
$ kubectl get svc -o wide -n=kube-system
NAME                    TYPE        CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)          AGE       SELECTOR
elasticsearch-logging   ClusterIP   10.xx.120.130   <none>        9200/TCP         11h       k8s-app=elasticsearch-logging
heapster                ClusterIP   10.xx.232.165   <none>        80/TCP           11h       k8s-app=heapster
kibana-logging          NodePort    10.xx.39.255    <none>        5601:31325/TCP   11h       k8s-app=kibana-logging
kube-dns                ClusterIP   10.xx.0.xx       <none>        53/UDP,53/TCP    12h       k8s-app=kube-dns
kubernetes-dashboard    NodePort    10.xx.xx.xx   <none>        80:32086/TCP     11h       k8s-app=kubernetes-dashboard
monitoring-influxdb     ClusterIP   10.13.199.138   <none>        8086/TCP         11h       k8s-app=influxdb
```